# Pdf Generation is failed, check the page markup is valid

Tags: visualforce

```
<apex:page standardController="Invoice__c" extensions="ShowallTimeCatdsCtrl2" sidebar="True"  showHeader="true"  docType="html-5.0" renderAs="{!if(downlodPdf==true,'pdf','')}">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock > 
            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top" >
                <apex:commandlink action="{!downloadPDF}" target="_blank" >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Download"  />
                </apex:commandLink>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                <apex:commandButton value="Back"  action="{!redirectInvPage}"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;


            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
        </apex:pageBlock> 

        <html>              
            <body>
                <apex:image url="{!$Resource.ATSLogo1}" width="240" height="120" style="float:right; padding-right:50px;" />
                <br> </br>
            <br> </br>
        <br> </br>
    <br> </br><br> </br>
<br> </br>
<div  style="height:100%; width:100%; padding-left:30px;padding-bottom:0px;">

    <table style="width:50%;" >
        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center; font-size:35px;  float:right; padding-right:50px; ">
                <h1  style = "color:#959595;"><u>INVOICE</u></h1>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
    <span style = "font-size:13px;float:right; padding-right:50px;" ><b>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    <br> <apex:outputText value="{0, date, MMMM d','  yyyy}" >
        &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:param value="{!now()}"  /> 
        </apex:outputText></br></b>
    <br>  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;   &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;<b>  INVOICE#:{!newInvoic.Name}</b></br>
</span>
<p style= "font-size:12px;margin-left:-30px; ">  <b>From :</b> &nbsp;  <b> Access Technology Solutions Inc.</b>
    <br/>
    <br>  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;141 W. Jackson Blvd..,</br>
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Ste. 3810,</br>
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Chicago, IL 60604,</br>
<br>&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Ph.: (312) 529-5159.</br></p>

<p style= "font-size:12px;margin-left:-30px;"> <b> To  &nbsp; &nbsp;  :  &nbsp; &nbsp;{!tcs[0].accountname__c}</b>
    <br/>
    <br> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;{!tcs[0].accountbillingcity__c}</br>
<br> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;{!tcs[0].accountbillingstate__c}</br>
<br> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;{!tcs[0].accountbillingcity__c}</br>
<br> &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;{!tcs[0].accountbillingPin__c}</br></p>
<br></br>
<table width="100%" height="auto" style="border:solid #000 0.5px; border-collapse: collapse; font-size:12px;margin-left:-30px;">
    <tr style ="background-color:#959595; text-align:center;">
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;"><b>Project Associate</b></td>
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;"><b>Project</b></td>
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;"><b>Service  Terms</b></td>
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;"><b>Due Date</b></td>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!selectedtimecards[0]}" var="sel">
        <tr style = "text-align:center;">
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;">{!sel.tc.project__r.owner.Name}</td>
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;">{!sel.tc.project__r.name}</td>
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;">
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" >
                    <apex:param value="{!objInvoices.Service_Term_From__c}"/> 
                </apex:outputText>&nbsp;-&nbsp;
                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" >
                    <apex:param value="{!objInvoices.Service_Term_To__c }"/>
                </apex:outputText></td>

            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:20%;">

                <apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM'/'dd'/'yyyy}" >
                    <apex:param value="{!newInvoic.Due_Date__c}"  /> 
                </apex:outputText></td>

        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>                             
</table><br/>
<table class="fixed" width="100%" style="border:solid #000 0.5px; border-collapse: collapse; font-size:12px; margin-left:-30px;">
    <tr style ="background-color:#959595; text-align:center;">
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:15%;"><b>Employee Name</b></td>
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:15%;"><b>Description</b></td>
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px;width:15%;"><b>Hours</b></td>

        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;"><b>Unit Price</b></td>
        <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;"><b>Amount</b></td>
    </tr>
    <apex:repeat value="{!selectedtimecardsWrpr}" var="var">
        <tr  style = "text-align:center;">
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;">{!var.empName}</td>
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;">{!var.decption}</td>
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;">{!var.totHrs}</td>
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;">{!var.hoursAndUnitprice}</td>
            <td style="border:solid #000 0.5px; width:15%;">{!var.totalAmt}</td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
</table>

<table style="width:100%; height:auto;">
    <tr style = "width:60%;">
        <td >

            <b>COMMENTS :</b> {!objInvoices.Comments__c}

        </td>

        <td style="width:43.6%;">
            <table style="width:92.5%; border:solid #000 0.5px; border-collapse: collapse;margin-left: 1.4%; " >
                <tr style = "width:40%;">
                    <td style="width:50%;font-size:13px;border:solid #000 0.5px;"><b>Total</b></td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-size:13px;border:solid #000 0.5px;text-align:center;">$ {!grandTotal}</td>   
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-size:13px; border:solid #000 0.5px;"><b>Payment/Credit</b></td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-size:13px; border:solid #000 0.5px;text-align:center;">$ {!payments}</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-size:13px; border:solid #000 0.5px;"><b>Due</b></td>
                    <td style="width:50%;font-size:13px; border:solid #000 0.5px;text-align:center;">$ {!grandTotal-payments}</td>  
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<!--<apex:pageBlock >  
<apex:outputLabel ><br>Comments :</br></apex:outputLabel>
<br> <apex:inputTextarea style="width:55%;font-size:13px;"  value="{!objInvoices.Comments__c}"/></br>
</apex:pageBlock>-->
<span class="h3" style="font-size:13px;">
    <br> Make all checks payable to<b> Access Technology Solutions, Inc</b></br>
<br>Remit your payments to the above address. If wiring, send them to <b> Chase,</b></br> 
<br>Acct# 181395661 R/T Number: 071000013. Chicago, IL 60604 USA</br>
&nbsp; <br> </br></span>
<br> </br>
<br> </br>


<br> <b>
<apex:outputText > <h4 style="text-align:center; margin-left:-500px;"> 
    Thank you for your business!</h4></apex:outputText></b>
</br>

<div style="background-color:#2E3640; color:white; width:100%; height:70px; border-radius:60px;font-size:12px;position:running; top:900px;margin-left:-30px;" ><p><br>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; Access Technology Solutions Inc. &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;   &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    Ph: 1.800.637.9569, &nbsp; Fax: 1.800.637.9569 </br>
<br>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; www.Accesstechnologys.com &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;   CONFIDENTIAL  &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;  Email:Info@accesstechnologys.com</br></p></div>
<apex:pageBlock > 
    <apex:pageBlockButtons location="top">
        <apex:commandButton value="Send Mail" action="{!sendPdf}"/>
        <apex:commandlink action="{!downloadPDF}" target="_blank" >
            <apex:commandButton value="Download"  />
        </apex:commandLink> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        <apex:commandButton value="Back"  action="{!redirectInvPage}"/>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
<br> </br>
<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:repeat value="{!allAttachments}" var="att">
        <a href="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!att.id}" download="{!att.name}" Target="_blank">{!att.name}</a><br/>
        <!-- <apex:image value="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.Id)}" />
<apex:iframe src="{!URLFOR($Action.Attachment.Download, att.Id)}"  />  -->
    </apex:repeat> 
</apex:pageBlock>

</div>
</body>
</html>
</apex:form>
<script type="text/javascript">
function newpagePDF() {
    var newpage = window.Open('/apex/nextgenerateinvoice?Id=','_blank');
}
</script>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: which error does that show?

Comment: Did you review this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_considerations.htm - and USE CSS instead of &nbsp.  Or at the very least proper HTML markup to provide spacing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way we're going to be able to tell you why this isn't working unless someone just happens to spot an error inside this code. Your code has numerous issues, but nothing I can see that would specifically cause the renderer to crash completely.

In this case, what you need to do is to start by using the divide and conquer technique. In this technique, you start by removing 90% of your code and see if it works. If it does, then add in another 10% of your code and see if it still works. Repeat until you get the error, which will at least narrow it down for us.

As a few side notes for things that could cause rendering errors:

- Nothing should be outside the `<html>` and `</html>` tags, except for `apex:page` and `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Your `script` and `apex:form` should be inside.
- `<br>` does not have a closing tag. You should always use `<br/>` instead.
- Use `apex:outputField` to properly escape output.

Other notes:

- Use more `class` attributes and fewer `style` attributes to make your code easier to read and maintain.
- All those `&nbsp;` are not particularly appropriate. Use styles to position text.
- Boolean values are already true or false, so there's really no need to say `downloadPDF==true`, you can just write `{!if(downloadPDF,'pdf','')}` instead.

Comment: I agree with everything you've stated and would add that regardless, he can't render any of the active content in a PDF, nor can he render a doctype that's HTML5 as a PDF using the Flying Saucer Render Engine.